# Как сделать страници из кнопок в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

[image: Пример кнопок]

как мне правильно реализовать список, то-есть в списке есть 50 строк, как мне все разделить по 1 странице в которой будет по 10 строк в каждой?

Answer (score 1):

Сделай список из этих кнопок, добавь в клавиатуру 10 первых кнопок, а в `callback_query` помести что-то подобное `page_from:10` и в обработчике `callback_query_handler`:

```
def callb(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboartMarkup()
    s = query.data.split(':')    
    for i in range((ints[1]),int(s[1])+10)
        keyboard.add( #сюда подставь свой список сконструированных кнопок.
                  )

    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вперед", callback_data="page_from:%s" % int(s[1]+10)))
```